# How to project array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a database of trucks and drivers and I want to have a property in my table which will denote when driver got into a certain truck and also keep the record of all trucks this driver had. So I created a mongoose schema which looks like this:

```
const driverHistorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    driver: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Employee",
        required: true,
    },
    history: [{
        transport: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Transport",
            required: true,
        },
        time: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        }
    }]
})
```

I have an aggregation for my transport (basically trucks) table and it goes somewhat like this:

```
const transports = await Transport.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "driverhistories",
        let: {
          "driverId": "$driver"
        },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$driver", "$$driverId"] } } },
          // { $project: { _id: 0, history: "$history" }, }
          { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { history: "$history" } } },
        ],
        as: "history"
      }

    },
    {
      "$unwind": {
        "path": "$history",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
      }
    },
  ]);
```

It gives me this kind of result:

```
 "_id": "xxxx",
 ....
 "history": {
                "history": [
                    {
                        "transport": "xxxx",
                        "time": "2023-11-02T09:19:14.654Z",
                        "_id": "xxxx"
                    },
                    {
                        "transport": "xxxx",
                        "time": "2023-11-03T11:23:50.956Z",
                        "_id": "xxxx"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

But my desired format is this:

```
    "_id": "xxxx"
    ....
    "history": [
                    {
                        "transport": "xxxx",
                        "time": "2023-11-02T09:19:14.654Z",
                        "_id": "xxxx"
                    },
                    {
                        "transport": "xxxx",
                        "time": "2023-11-03T11:23:50.956Z",
                        "_id": "xxxx"
                    }
                ]
```

So what I need is to remove the outer object and leave just the array.

I tried to project it many ways but the closest ones to success were these 2:
{ $project: { _id: 0, history: "$history" }, }
{ $project: { _id: 0, transport: "$history.transport", time: "$history.time" } },

Both gave me not that I wanted but just different formats of data display but still an array inside an object.

Comment: Did you try ` { $project: { _id: 0, history: "$history.history" }`

Comment: At what point?
In my $lookup I can't do it because there is no $history.history yet. And if you mean after that, I can't do it because I would need to specify all the other fields as well and I don't have a certain amount of fields and they differ for each transport

Comment: If you want that in addition to other fields, use `$addFields` instead of `$project`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired output where the history field is just an array without the outer object, you can use the $unwind stage followed by the $group stage to reshape the data. Here's the updated aggregation pipeline to achieve this:

```
const transports = await Transport.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "driverhistories",
      let: {
        "driverId": "$driver"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$driver", "$$driverId"] } }
        },
        {
          $project: { _id: 0, history: 1 } // Project only the 'history' field
        }
      ],
      as: "history"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$history",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      // Reconstruct the 'history' field as an array
      history: { $push: "$history.history" },
      // Other fields from the Transport document
      // Add them as needed
    }
  }
]);

console.log(transports);
```

In this updated aggregation:

1. The $project stage inside the $lookup pipeline selects only the
   history field, eliminating the outer object.

   The $group stage reconstructs the history field as an array using
   $push and groups the results based on the _id field from the
   original Transport document.

   You can include other fields from the Transport document in the
   $group stage as needed.

This should give you the desired format where the history field is an array without the outer object.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have strict number of fields for this table so if I use $group I would need to reformat it quite a few times again